# DistCp fault tolerance between two remote clusters

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, distcp

I need to copy a directory of from one cluster to another with similar HDFS (both are MAPR clusters).

I am planed to use `DistCp` Java API. But I wanted to avoid duplicate copies of files in the directory. I wanted to know whether these operations are fault tolerant? I.e if the files are not copied completely due to loss of connection, if the DistCp initiates the copies again to copy a file properly?

Comment: pls respond to the answers. so that more users will get motivation to give prompt answers

Answer (score 0):

`distcp` uses MapReduce to effect its distribution, error handling and recovery, and reporting.

Please see [Update and Overwrite](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/distcp.html#uo)

> ***You can use -overwrite option to avoid duplicates Moreover, you can check update option as well. If network connection fails, once its connection recovered then you can re-initiate with overwrite option***

See the examples of -update and -overwrite as mentioned in above guide link.

Comment: @user2021147 was my answer helpful? if yes, pls vote-up "accepted by owner" thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link for refactored distcp:
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-distcp/DistCp.html

As "@RamPrasad G" mentioned, I guess you have no option other than redo the distcp in case of network failure.

Some good reads:

> Hadoop distcp network failures with WebHDFS

http://www.ghostar.org/2015/08/hadoop-distcp-network-failures-with-webhdfs/

> Distcp between two HA Cluster

http://henning.kropponline.de/2015/03/15/distcp-two-ha-cluster/

> Transferring Data to/from Altiscale via S3 using DistCp

https://documentation.altiscale.com/transferring-data-using-distcp
This page has a link for a shell script with retry, which could be helpful to you.

Note: Thanks to original authors.